# How to effectively turn high resolution images into a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

- I have 24 frames (`frame-%d.png`)
- I want to turn them into a video that will be 1 second long
- That means that each frame should play for 1/24 seconds

I'm trying to figure out the correct settings in order to achieve that:

```
await new Promise((resolve) => {
  ffmpeg()
    .on('end', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('done')
        resolve()
      }, 100)
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      throw new Error(err)
    })
    .input('/my-huge-frames/frame-%d.png')
    .inputFPS(1/24)
    .output('/my-huge-video.mp4')
    .outputFPS(24)
    .noAudio()
    .run()
```

1. Are my `inputFPS(1/24)` & `outputFPS(24)` correct ?
2. Each `frame-%d.png` is huge: **32400PX x 32400PX** (~**720Mb**). Will `ffmpeg` be able to generate such a video, and if so, will the video be playable? If not, **what is the maximum resolution each `frame-%d.png` should have instead?**
3. Since the process will be quite heavy, I believe using the command line could be more appropriate. In that case, what is the equivalent of the above Js code in the command line (as in `ffmpeg -framerate etc...`) ?

Answer (score 1):

your output image size is too large for most common video codecs.

- h.264 2048x2048
- h.265 8192×4320
- av1 7680×4320

You may be able to do raw RGB or raw YUV, but that is going to be huge
~1.5GB per frame for YUV420...

what are you planning to play this on, I know of some dome theaters that theoretically able run something like 15 simultaneous 4k feeds... but they are processed before hand...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not planning on playing th video on a 32000PX x 32000PX "screen" :D I know that's practically impossible.  i wanted to play the video on 720x720 screen. The reason it's so big it's because I'd like to zoom into each frame while the video is playing because there's a lot detail "deep" inside each frame. But I think I'm going the wrong way about this. I'm trying to do this programmatically instead of using something like Premiere because I don't know how to use Premiere.

Comment: that is a cool project, you might be able to replicate it with something like HLS / DASH where you have a playlist that describes each region, but you are still talking ~2000 individual 720x720 tiles per frame